# get image from scanner with PHP or BASH file?

Tags: php, bash

Can I get image from scanner with PHP or BASH file and process it? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: What mean `and processs it`, what would you do?

Comment: I mean copy it to a directory and save the image address in database

Answer (score 2):

`scanadf` from the SANE project can be used to drive a scanner from the command line. Read the [man page](http://www.sane-project.org/man/scanadf.1.html) for available options.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14084010/352449), the [SANE PROJECT](http://www.sane-project.org/) gives you the ability to scan through the command line by calling `scanimage` with a few parameters.

To achieve your goal of scanning the document and moving it to a specific location:

```
<?php
$mode = 'gray';
$reso = 150;
$path = '/my/document/path/myFile.jpg';

/* scan the document in Gray Scale, with 150dpi of resolution
 * pipe a call to convert the resulting document to a JPEG
 * save the document to your desired location
 */ 
exec("scanimage --mode ".$mode." --resolution ".$reso." | pnmtojpeg > ".path);

// check if the document exists...
// save the contents of $path to the database...
?>
```